# Python requests posting forms

Tags: python, forms, post, python-requests

I am trying to post a http form and get the response. I understand "requests" might be the way to go. I am trying to post to the login form on this page: www.dust2.dk/Login comparing the response to check if I recieved the error "Der er ikke registreret nogen bruger med den email" ("There is no user registered with that email")

Somehow the form is not being posted or the response is not being saved. I have tried searching around for a solution, to no avail. Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#imports
import requests

#code
def main():

        r = requests.post('http://dust2.dk/Login', data = {'email' : 'testmail@test.dk', 'password' : 'testest'})

        if 'Der er ikke registreret nogen bruger med den email' in r.text:
                print 'You done did it mate!'
        else:
                print 'Nope! Keep trying'
```

As you might guess the result is: "Nope! Keep trying" If I print out the response r, i simply get the source of the page www.dust2.dk/Login. Do you have any pointers of what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Print out the content and response code of `r`. Why guess at what's going on when the answer is right there?

Comment: Im not guessing :) That error is shown upon submitting the form with a wrong email. I simply make python search the html response for me, instead of scrolling through it myself. I forgot to mention, the response im getting is simply the code of the original page: www.dust2.dk/Login. I will update my question.

Comment: How do you know the website is expecting fields named `email` and `password`? This question is too broad and can't be answered without a ton of back-and-forth. You should ask the website operator for help logging in via Python.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question. I simply look at the form in the pages source to see the names of these fields. Such as: <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="borderedBox">

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar the other day by sending a post request in Python. I followed [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#data). You need to import and use urllib and urllib2.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://dust2.dk/Login'
values = {'email' : 'email@here',
          'password' : 'blahblah'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

EDIT: actually follow [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#data) guide instead if you're using Python 3.
See if that does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually started out with urllib(2) on a more advanced site, which I could not get to work. I am going to try your code on the current site and report back the results.

Comment: No luck with the example. Same issue. Upon printing the_page i simply get the original page. I will try the guide you mentioned aswell.